# Read multiple .gpx files

Tags: r, loops, gps, gis

Suppose I have a number of *.gpx* files (these contain GPX waypoint data from a Garmin eTrex).  I want to load them into R with different names and manipulate them.

I can read one file thus:

```
library(maptools)
gpx.raw <- readGPS(i = "gpx", f = "file1_w_12_f_ddf.gpx", type="w")
```

Suppose I want to read a number of them into memory.  I could try a *for* loop:

```
files <- list.files(".",pattern = "*.gpx")
for(x in files){

    #Create new file name
    temp <- strsplit(x,"_",fixed=TRUE)
    visit.id <- sapply(temp,FUN=function(x){paste(x[1],x[4],substr(x[5],1,3),sep="_")})

    #read file with new filename
    assign(visit.id, readGPS(i = "gpx", f = x, type="w"))
}
```

Running above program yields following error:

> Error in read.table(con <- textConnection(gpsdata), fill = TRUE, ...) : 
>     no lines available in input
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   running command 'C:\PROGRA~2\GPSBabel\gpsbabel.exe -w -i gpx -f file1_w_12_f_ddf.gpx -o tabsep -F -' had status 1

Note that I was able to read this file on its own, so it would seem it has nothing to do with the file itself but with running readGPS in a loop.

In general I still find it very confusing how *R* treats variables like *x* above.  I am not sure how to modify the argument to readGPS from the stand alone instance `f = "file1_w_12_f_ddf.gpx"`:  Should it be `x`, or `f = x`, or `f = "x"`, or what?  Or maybe the problem is in the call to GPSBabel...

I include a sample file below so you can copy it to text editor, and save as *.gpx.* twice with different names and try yourself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx
 version="1.0"
 creator="GPSBabel - http://www.gpsbabel.org"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
 <time>2010-09-14T18:35:43Z</time>
 <bounds minlat="18.149888897" minlon="-96.747799935" maxlat="50.982883293" maxlon="121.640266674"/>
<wpt lat="38.855549991" lon="-94.799016668">
<ele>325.049072</ele>
 <name>GARMIN</name>
 <cmt>GARMIN</cmt>
 <desc>GARMIN</desc>
 <sym>Flag</sym>
 </wpt>
 <wpt lat="50.982883293" lon="-1.463899976">
 <ele>35.934692</ele>
 <name>GRMEUR</name>
 <cmt>GRMEUR</cmt>
 <desc>GRMEUR</desc>
 <sym>Flag</sym>
 </wpt>
 <wpt lat="25.061783362" lon="121.640266674">
 <ele>38.097656</ele>
 <name>GRMTWN</name>
 <cmt>GRMTWN</cmt>
 <desc>GRMTWN</desc>
 <sym>Flag</sym>
 </wpt>
 </gpx>
```

NOTE: To run *readGPS* you will need the open source GPSBabel program installed and referenced in your PATH variable.

Comment: Regarding the `f` argument to `readGPS`: passing `x` will work only if it's the second argument in the call to `readGPS`, passing `f=x` will work no matter where you place it and passing `f="x"` won't work at all (it will pass the character "x" to the parameter `f` regardless of what you've stored in a variable named `x`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the code was fine, the problem is with the file names.  GPSBabel does not like names with white spaces.  So "1_San José Baldi_Pernam_14_sep.gpx" is a problem, "1_San_José_Baldi_Pernam_14_sep.gpx" is not.

Answer (score 6):

Fred,

After installing GPSBabel and updating the PATH variable, your code snippet ran fine. I have two objects names `test1.gpx_NA_NA` and `test2.gpx_NA_NA` with three observations of 28 variables. Is that right? I assume the NA bit in the file names is due to how you are defining `visit.id` and my test file names not fitting into that paradigm.

Have you tried this on a fresh instance of R?

FWIW, I would probably read all of these files into a single list object. I find dealing with a list object easier than having lots of different objects floating around. For example,

```
files <- dir(pattern = "\\.gpx")
#Replace all space characters with a "_". Replace with the character of your choice.
lapply(files, function(x) file.rename(from = x, to = gsub("\\s+", "_", x)))

#Reread in files with better names:
files <- dir(pattern = "\\.gpx")
out <- lapply(files, function(x) readGPS(i = "gpx", f = x, type = "w"))
names(out) <- files
```

and `out` is now a list of 2, where each object is a data.frame with the name of the file that it was associated with previously. Using something from the `*apply` family has the benefit leaving a clean working space behind as well. Using the for-loop results in `x`, `temp`, and `visit.id` hanging out afterwords. You could wrap them up into a function call, but just using `lapply` will be more straight forward I think.

Comment: Ha! Well it does not run on mine?!?!  I wonder whether it has something to do with Windows.  I use my laptop as user not admin so perhaps permissions get messed up along the way.  BTW I tried your code and got same error.  Weird thing is I can still access one file at a time.

Comment: @Chase I think I found the problem.  It has to do with file names.  Currently the files were handed to me with long names with accents, etc like "1_San José Baldi_Pernam_14_sep.gpx".  When I change the name to "test1" it worked.  BTW thanks for the `lapply` pointer.

Comment: @Chase Actually the problem was not the accents but the white spaces.  So "1_San José Baldi_Pernam_14_sep.gpx" is a problem, "1_San_José_Baldi_Pernam_14_sep.gpx" is not.  Just wasted 3 hours.  The joys of programing...

Comment: @Fred - Glad you got it figured out. I updated my answer with a bit of `regex` to deal with the offending spaces. And thanks for showing me readGPS, I have 2.5 years worth of Garmin 500 cycling data with GPS tracks, speed, elevation, HR, and power that I've always wanted to play with in R!

Comment: @Chase - Thanks.  BTW it took me quite a while to figure this out.  Originally I tried to read .gpx as XML files and parse them in `r`.  Another way to go, though this is much neater I think.  Then you can append any other data, export waypoints and data as a .csv and map in QGIS. Enjoy!

Comment: @Chase - BTW you have replaced spaces with underscores in the files vector but not at the system level.  readGPS will not find renamed files.

Comment: @doh - that's note useful at all is it? Not sure what I was thinking about earlier. `file.rename()` will do what you need if you want to use R for that part of the analysis. Answer edited accordingly. Sorry again, had a brain fart earlier.

Comment: @Chase , the readOGR command in the rgdal library reads the gpx files without needing to install the other babel software.