# Reference GPSBabel in PATH variable to use in R

Tags: r, path, gps, gpx

I have read this question and answer here [Read multiple .gpx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397523/read-multiple-gpx-files) on reading GPX files in R. At the end of the question, the question setter notes "To run readGPS you will need the open source GPSBabel program installed and referenced in your PATH variable."

I have installed GPSBabel, but am unsure how to link it to R so that the supplied code works.

```
library(maptools)
gpx.raw <- readGPS(i = "gpx", f = "Data/Waypoints_11-MAY-18.gpx", type="w")
```

Running the code at the head of the question (above) with my own filename returns the error

```
Error in readGPS(i = "gpx", f = "Data/Waypoints_11-MAY-18.gpx", type = "w") :
gpsbabel not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I downloaded and installed [GPSBabel](https://www.gpsbabel.org/download.html#downloading), copied of the path for where it installed, and then:

```
 setwd("C:/Program Files (x86)/GPSBabel")
```

That took care of it for me, not sure if there is a simpler way to do this.